# Handling NULL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am facing issue when trying to handle null.

Here is example

I have a table

```
Create table Test_Table 
(
id int null,
pName varchar(10)
)
GO
```

Id column has `NULL` value.

```
INSERT INTO Test_Table 
SELECT NULL, 'A' UNION 
SELECT NULL,'B' UNION 
SELECT NULL, 'C' UNION 
SELECT NULL,'D' 
GO
```

Now when I execute different select statements, last two conditions are failing. I can use `ISNULL` to handle it but there are approx 500 SPs which I would need to change.

So, I need solution apart from that, if possible.

```
SELECT * FROM Test_Table WHERE id is NULL --True

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
SELECT * FROM Test_Table WHERE id=NULL --True


SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
SELECT * FROM Test_Table WHERE id=id --False. Why???

Declare @ID INT = 0

SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
Select case when @ID > 0 then @ID else id end as Statements, * 
From   Test_Table  
Where  ID = case when @ID > 0 then @ID else ID END -- Fails. Why??
```

When **Id=NULL** is true then why **Id=Id** is false??

Thanks!

Comment: Forget about the `ANSI_NULLS` setting. It is deprecated, non standard, and not compatible with some product features (such as filtered indexes or indexed views)

Comment: And why do you need to use `WHERE id=id`? Just remove the whole `WHERE` clause and you have all the rows of the table - which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at remarks on MS Docs about [IS NULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-null-transact-sql):

> **Remarks**
>   To determine whether an expression is NULL, use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL instead of comparison operators (such as = or !=).
>   Comparison operators return **UNKNOWN** when either or both arguments are NULL.

And at [SET ANSI_NULLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql) MS Docs:

> SET ANSI_NULLS ON affects a comparison only if one of the operands of the comparison is either a variable that is NULL or a literal NULL. **If both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the setting does not affect the comparison.**

Let me add some other records to your table:

```
INSERT INTO Test_Table 
VALUES (NULL, 'A'),(NULL,'B'),(NULL,'C'),(NULL,'D'),(1,'E'),(2,'F');
```

Now, your query:

> ```
> SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
> SELECT * FROM Test_Table WHERE id=id;
> ```

Returns:

> ```
> id | pName
> -: | :----
>  1 | E    
>  2 | F
> ```

And the same for your second query:

> ```
> Declare @ID INT = NULL
>
> SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
> SELECT CASE WHEN @ID > 0 THEN @ID ELSE id END AS Statements, * 
> FROM   Test_Table  
> WHERE  ID = CASE WHEN @ID > 0 THEN @ID ELSE ID END
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Statements | id | pName
> ---------: | -: | :----
>          1 |  1 | E    
>          2 |  2 | F
> ```

Null indicates lack of value and you must explicitly check for NULL values using IS NULL:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
SELECT * FROM Test_Table WHERE id IS NULL;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=df55e1bfbf9576219c02c5bd7c9ca6d1)*

Comment: And more: the condition `WHERE id=id OR id IS NULL` is always true and could be omitted altogether!

Comment: "UNKNOWN" is like "FALSE", except that NOT(FALSE) is TRUE, but NOT(UNKNOWN) is UNKNOWN.  And even the formula "id = id" comes out UNKNOWN when id is NULL.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/null-and-unknown-transact-sql describes this in terms where the "UNKNOWN" is represented by a boolean term that itself is NULL - e.g. (TRUE) OR (UNKNOWN) = TRUE.